# JOINning two List-of-Lists to one

Tags: python, python-3.x, inner-join

The issue before me is to JOIN, SQL-Like, two arrays, with a "key" formed from two columns, YEAR and MONTH. The two arrays represent incomes (for each Year and month) and likewise expenses. I want to JOIN them, using the key, producing another array with four columns: YEAR, MONTH, INCOME, EXPENSE.

The two arrays I have are:

```
income = [["2019","Jan.", 2000],
          ["2019","Feb.", 1500],
          [ ---- , ---  , --- ],
          ["2019","Dec.", 1200],
          ["2020","Jan.", 1400],
          [ ---- , ---  , --- ],
          ["2020","Dec.", 1300]]

Expenses = [["2019","Jan.", 1800],
            ["2019","Feb.", 1400],
            [ ---- , ---  , --- ],
            ["2019","Dec.", 1100],
            ["2020","Jan.", 1300],
            [ ---- , ---  , --- ],
            ["2020","Dec.", 1200]]
```

And the desired result is:

```
Joined =   [["2019","Jan.", 2000, 1800],
            ["2019","Feb.", 1500, 1400],
            [ ---- , ---  , ---   ----],
            ["2019","Dec.", 1200, 1100],
            ["2020","Jan.", 1400, 1300],
            [ ---- , ---  , ---   ----],
            ["2020","Dec.", 1300, 1200]]
```

What do I do? List comprehension? for loop? What would be the pythonic way?

Comment: Do whatever you want. This is going to be difficult to do with a list comprehension because a list comprehension is for mapping/filtering operations, doing a join would require a very inefficient algorithm, instead, you should use a dict as an index. Generally, if you are thinking in terms of joins, then `list` is the wrong data structure. The "pythonic" way would be to use a more appropriate data structure (or maybe just use a database, Python is already distributed with sqlite)

Comment: You should look into the Pandas library. It makes working with data like this a breeze.

Comment: Also, you really **must** provide a [mcve]. The example you provided raises a `SyntaxError`. What is `[ ---- , ---  , --- ]` supposed to be?

Comment: Are they always the same position or it might be 2020 in row 1 of income list, and 2019 in row 1 of expenses, and you need to match them accordingly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: The `[ ---- , ---  , --- ]` is just a kind of `Dito`. The actual arrays are two or more years each with all 12 months. Just delete these lines and you got two executable input array.

Comment: @Bharel: Yes they are at the same positions and no month is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) to convert your lists (**income** and **Expenses**) into Dataframes, merge them (in this case it's basically an inner join on Year and Month) and then convert the Dataframe you get into a list of lists.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(income, columns=["Year", "Month", "X"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Expenses, columns=["Year", "Month", "Y"])
joined = df1.merge(df2, on=["Year", "Month"]).values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['2019', 'Jan.', 2000, 1800], ['2019', 'Feb.', 1500, 1400], ['2019', 'Dec.', 1200, 1100], ['2020', 'Jan.', 1400, 1300], ['2020', 'Dec.', 1300, 1200]]
```

PS: I removed all the `[ ---- , ---  , --- ]` from the two lists if you're wondering why they are not in the output.

Comment: Thank you! I am not  a seasoned pythonista, less than a year experience and Pandas was not in my toolbox! I guess it will be now...
Thanks again!

Comment: And producing the balance was as simple as subtracting two columns, another line!


` df_joined['balance'] = df_joined['incomes'] - df_joined['expenses']`

Answer (score 0):

Without pandas:

```
import operator
import itertools

def join(*lists, exclude_positions=()):
    """Join list rows
    
    Example:
        >>> list_a = [["2019","Jan.", 2000],
                      ["2019","Feb.", 1500]]
        >>> list_b = [["2019","Jan.", 1800],
                      ["2019","Feb.", 1400]]
        >>> join(list_a, list_b, exclude_positions=(0,1))
        [["2019","Jan.", 2000, 1800],
        ["2019","Feb.", 1500, 1400]]

    Args:
        *lists: lists to join
        exclude_positions: positions to exclude from merging. The equivalent
        positions from the first list will be used.
    """
    lists_length = len(lists[0])

    if lists_length == 0:
        return []

    if not all(len(l) == lists_length for l in lists):
        raise ValueError("Lists must have the same length")

    iterators = []
    iterators.append(iter(lists[0]))
    
    for l in lists[1:]:
        columns_taken = [i for i in range(len(l[0])) if i not in exclude_positions]
        if len(columns_taken) == 0:
            continue
        iterator = map(operator.itemgetter(*columns_taken), l)
        if len(columns_taken) == 1:
            iterator = ((i,) for i in iterator)
    
        iterators.append(iterator)


    return [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(row))  for row in zip(*iterators)]
```

My solution is 100x to 500x faster than the pandas solution for 4, 120 and 1200 rows checked:

```
py -m timeit -s "import temp2" "temp2.join(temp2.income, temp2.Expenses, exclude_positions=(0,1))"
10000 loops, best of 5: 24.2 usec per loop

py -m timeit -s "import pandas as pd; import temp2" "pd.DataFrame(temp2.income, columns=['Year', 'Month', 'X']).merge(pd.DataFrame(temp2.Expenses, columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Y']), on=['Year', 'Month']).values.tolist()"
50 loops, best of 5: 8.42 msec per loop
```

This is because I'm using efficient C-level iterators and functions, do not create intermediate data types, and are not matching by keys, but by row number according to your comment. I also do not need any module outside the standard library.

A better solution with pandas would be to merge rows normally without lookup:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(temp2.income, columns=['Year', 'Month', 'X'])
b = pd.DataFrame(temp2.Expenses, columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Y'])
result = pd.DataFrame({'Year': a['Year'], 'Month': a['Month'], 'X': a['X'], 'Y': b['Y']}).values.tolist()
```

My solution is still 3x faster than that, but the pandas is short and concise.